# Display image instead of URL

Tags: image, url, asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed a ASP.NET MVC application with signalr to display the records on the page.
My table has five columns (jobid [int], name[varchar], lastexecutiondate[datetime],status[int],imageurl[string])

Here is my markup from view page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        // Proxy created on the fly
        var job = $.connection.jobHub;

        // Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke it
        job.client.displayStatus = function () {
            getData();
        };

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();
        getData();
    });

    function getData() {
        var $tbl = $('#tblJobInfo');
        $.ajax({
            url: '../api/values',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $tbl.empty();
                    $tbl.append(' <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Last Executed Date</th><th>Status</th><th>Image URL</th></tr>');
                    var rows = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        rows.push(' <tr><td>' + data[i].JobID + '</td><td>' + data[i].Name + '</td><td>' + data[i].LastExecutionDate.toString().substr(0, 10) + '</td><td>' + data[i].Status + '</td><td>' + data[i].imageurl + '</td></tr>');
                    }
                    $tbl.append(rows.join(''));
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table id="tblJobInfo" style="text-align:center;margin-left:10px">
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

And below is my code to get the data from database

```
SqlDependency.Start(connection.ConnectionString);
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                        .Select(x => new JobInfo()
                        {
                            JobID = x.GetInt32(0),
                            Name = x.GetString(1),
                            LastExecutionDate = x.GetDateTime(2),
                            Status = x.GetString(3),
                            imageurl = x.GetString(4)
                        }).ToList();
```

I want to display the image instead of the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need to create an image tag in your JavaScript table row function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   rows.push(' <tr><td>' + data[i].JobID + '</td><td>' + data[i].Name + '</td><td>' + data[i].LastExecutionDate.toString().substr(0, 10) + '</td><td>' + data[i].Status + '</td><td><img src="' + data[i].imageurl + '"/></td></tr>');
}
```

I can think of a couple of ways to address your comment below.  In code, create a helper function to do this for you:

```
SqlDependency.Start(connection.ConnectionString);
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                        .Select(x => new JobInfo()
                        {
                            JobID = x.GetInt32(0),
                            Name = x.GetString(1),
                            LastExecutionDate = x.GetDateTime(2),
                            Status = x.GetString(3),
                            imageurl = GetImageUrl(x.GetString(3))
                        }).ToList();

private string GetImageUrl(int status){
   switch(status){
     case 1:
        return "some.jpg"
     case 2:
        return "someother.jpg"
     default:
        return "blank.jpg"
   }
}
```

I don't know your code that well, so this assumes that your select is not being cast to a SQL statement (it doesn't appear that it is).

To do the same thing client side, you would implement the GetImageUrl function as a JavaScript function and to the same type of thing.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   rows.push(' <tr><td>' + data[i].JobID + '</td><td>' + data[i].Name + '</td><td>' + data[i].LastExecutionDate.toString().substr(0, 10) + '</td><td>' + data[i].Status + '</td><td><img src="' + GetImageUrl(data[i].Status) + '"/></td></tr>');
}

function GetImageUrl(status){
  switch(status){
         case 1:
            return "some.jpg"
         case 2:
            return "someother.jpg"
         default:
            return "blank.jpg"
       }
}
```

Comment: +1 worked for me.. just for learning purpose can u suggest me how can i generate url at run time.

Ex.: if status = 1 , then URL ="some.jpg"
if status = 2 , then url = "someother.jpg"
else "blank.jpg"

Comment: Sure, i put a couple of thoughts in the answer for you.  PS - not 100% on my JS switch implementation syntax off the top of my head

Comment: You are awesome. I have implemented that and it is working absolutely fine. Thanks for assisting me :)